# Is there any method to add bootstrap style to Django password input field?

Tags: html, css, django

I'm trying to add a registration page to my Django project and I have made the registration form in the forms.py file.

```
 
class createUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

        widgets = {
            'username' : forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-input','placeholder':'Username...'}),
            'email' : forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-input','placeholder':'Email...'}),
            'password1' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-input','placeholder':'Password'}),
            'password2' : forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control form-input','placeholder':'Re-type password'}),

        }
```

HTML

```
<h4>Sign in</h4>
                <div class="form-container">
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                <div class="form-render" style="display: block;">
                   {% csrf_token %}
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                    {{form.username}}
                </div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                    {{form.email}}
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                    {{form.password1}}
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-bottom: 1rem;">
                    {{form.password2}}
                    </div>
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 0px; outline-color: #167896; background-color:#167896; width: 15rem; margin-left: 1.5rem;">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                    <div style="display: flex; margin-left: 1.75rem; margin-top: 1rem; margin-bottom: 0rem;">
                        <p>Already have an account?</p><a style="text-decoration: none; " class="forgot" href="{% url 'login' %}">&nbsp Log in</a> 
                      </div>

                </div>
```

After rendering out HTML, bootstrap styles are not added to the password input fields. This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoH7m.png) of my output page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to send the bootstrap classes as `attrs`. Just use [Crispy Forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
pip install django-crispy-forms
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "crispy_forms",
]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = "bootstrap4"
```

HTML:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form method="post">
    {{ my_formset|crispy }}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

But does the class appear in the source code? if it is showing, then your bootstrap file is not loading or you are using the wrong measurements

Anyway you can do a test, create something like this:

```
<style>.form-a{width:100%:!important; height:36px; border:green;}</style>
```

Put the code above on your page! Now place the form-a class in your `<input>` and see if it renders with a green border and takes up all the available space, otherwise it means that the classes are not in the rendered source code (client side) and, therefore, there is another problem with your non-bootstrap-related code. If it's like I said, your bootstrap file is not loading or you are using the wrong classes for what you intend to do.

Comment: `class createUserForm(UserCreationForm):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(createUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password1'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control',})
        self.fields['password2'].widget = forms.PasswordInput(attrs = {'class': 'form-control',})
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
        widgets = {

  }
  `  It came out as I intended when the form was modified like this

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to skin this cat, but my preferred method is to use the `django-bootstrap4` package: https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap4/

- Install it in your `venv`: `pip install django-bootstrap4`
- Add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    "bootstrap4",
    # ...
)
```

- Use it in a template:

```html
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<h4>Sign in</h4>
<div class="form-container">
    <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

It will automatically take care of displaying errors properly. If you need to do any custom actions for fields, you can also loop through the fields:

```html
{% load bootstrap4 %}

<h4>Sign in</h4>
<div class="form-container">
    <form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% bootstrap_field field %}
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Good luck!